# Force open button for XML file download in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We are looking for a client-side way to force Internet Explorer to show the Open button when downloading an XML file.

Normally the download bar looks like this:

[image: IE download bar with "Open" button]

When downloading an XML file, however, no "Open" button is shown:

[image]

How to configure IE/Windows in a way that the "Open" button is shown for each file download?

I've already read about the `X-Download-Options` HTTP header, unfortunately, we must look for a client-side solution as we cannot alter the web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out the following: Windows had associated the file type "xml" with Internet Explorer (control panel -> default programs -> set associations). This triggers IE to not show the Open button anymore, we don't know why exactly, however, when associating xml with Notepad, the Open button reappears.

If anyone has a better solution to always force the Open button pleas come forward. In the meantime we are going to use this workaround.